# Add dynamic dependencies via command line

Tags: gradle, plugins, command-line-interface

Is it possible to use CLI to add a jar with Gradle plugin (or task) to the build classpath without modifying `build.gradle`? Can the add JAR be resolved from Maven repository?

Is `buildscript { dependencies { classpath }}` controllable from CLI? And can I use CLI to make Gradle to resolve the JAR from Maven?

Basically I need to achieve the same situation as with Maven, which allows invoking any plugin by

```
mvn <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>:<plugin-version>:<plugin-goal>
```

I'm writing a pair of [Maven and Gradle plugins](https://github.com/JV-ration/project-info-plugins) to extract information about projects and their dependencies into JSON file, which can be later processed programatically. The idea is to be able to apply it on a large number of OSS projects and, therefore, without modifying them.

Comment: "Is it possible to use CLI to apply a JAR with Gradle plugin from Maven repository" this statement needs clarification. Do you want to add a jar task to the build? Do you want to add a jar to the compile/runtime dependencies? It's unclear what you want

Comment: I updated the statement

Comment: "build classpath" is still ambiguous as it could mean `buildscript { classpath ... }}` or `dependencies { compile ... }}` or something else? runtime etc

Comment: I meant `buildscript { dependencies { classpath }}`. The one, which is used to make jar with custom plugin class available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I get it now

myinit-script.gradle

```
if (hasProperty('extraDependencies')) {
    def extraDeps = property('extraDependencies').split(',')
    allprojects {
        buildscript {
            dependencies {
                classpath extraDeps
            }
        }
    }
}
```

command line

```
gradlew --init-script myinit-script.gradle -PextraDependencies=org.foo:bar:1.0,org.foo:baz:1.2 build
```

Comment: Seems my question is indeed very confusing, sorry ;( 

I need to make custom plugin (or straight task) available on build script classpath and to invoke it. Without adding `apply plugin` statement and `buildscript { dependencies { classpath }}` to `build.gradle`

Comment: Updated answer to do it via an [init-script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script)