# How do I preload some dependencies/plugins in maven before pom.xml?

Tags: java, spring, maven, kotlin, gradle

we are creating a lot of short lived test projects at my work. Dozens of them each day. we have about 10 dependencies that we use internally at our workplace - these are all custom plugins.
I want to get people to not have to mess with their pom.xml for the official dependencies just to get started. so either create a bash script that has all the dependencies on cli...or try to inherit one common xml from all these pom.xml.

I looked at other answers (like [Reusing ant-snippets in multi-module maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056194/reusing-ant-snippets-in-multi-module-maven-build/27869461#27869461)), but i dont think these work. im also looking to see if i can use multimodule builds, but then it is even more boilerplate.

i was also looking at maven-dependency-plugin, but I think it only copies/downloads dependencies...u still need to add them to pom.xml.

I also saw some similar questions in gradle area ([Add dynamic dependencies via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607153/add-dynamic-dependencies-via-command-line)), but unsure if it works in maven.

so my question stands - how do I add a large number of dependencies to a maven project, WITHOUT messing with the pom.xml file ?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: "we are creating a lot of short lived test projects at my work. Dozens of them each day" that is exactly what [maven archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) are supposed to solve

Comment: Simply create a parent pom which contains all definitions of plugins/configuration and a BOM file which contains the default dependencies. You project pom will contain only a parent and a usage of a BOM (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#importing-dependencies) That will give you a clean separation of concern...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a parent pom dependency, include all needed dependencies in it and then use it as parent dependency for your small projects, like this:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>some-parent-pom</artifactId>
  <version>DEV-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Do not forget to run `mvn clean install` to install the parent POM to your local repository.

Comment: i did not understand this. is this in the same directory as pom.xml ? the other file will be called "some-parent-pom.xml" ? im a bit unsure of this.