# problem in Gradle adding dependencies through commandline

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to add a bunch of dependencies through the commandline. This is because my workplace has a bunch of plugins that we want to preload into every project. and we dont want devs to mess about their gradle files.

So I looked at this older issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40613776/112050 and tried to do the same in this repo https://github.com/arakoodev/bug-gradle
however, I'm constantly getting a `"cannot find symbol"` error:

`error screenshot` - https://github.com/arakoodev/bug-gradle/blob/main/error%20msg.png:

[image]

I'm only using an empty `springboot` application, but moved the dependency declaration from `build.gradle` into `myinit-script.gradle`.

The code can't find the classes from the springboot dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're mixing a few patterns...

If you want to include `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.0` as a dependency, and not merely add it as a classpath, using `classpath` wont accomplish this.

I did verify that if you change your `myinit-script.gradle` to the following, it will work:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

What's going on here?

- Changed `initscript` to `allprojects` to apply it to all projects.

  - Perhaps you could still use `initscript`, but I think the `-I` is accomplishing this.  Anyway, followed the pattern from here:
  - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html
- You cant include dependencies unless you have already applied the `java` plugin, so that was added.
- `classpath` doesn't include a dependency, `implementation` does, so changed that.

Now, when I run this, `gradle -I .\myinit-script.gradle clean build`, I get a clean compile.